# Is the exact solution of the wave equation for the scattering of waves by a disk/cylinder an open problem?

Tags: open-problems, closed-form-expressions, wave-equation, research

The solution exact solution of the Helmholtz equation for the scattering of waves by a sphere is relatively straightforward and has been [known](https://scholar.google.be/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=J.%20W.%20Strutt%20%28Lord%20Rayleigh%29%2C%20%E2%80%9CInvestigation%20of%20the%20disturbance%20produced%20by%20a%20spherical%20obstacle%20on%20the%20waves%20of%20sound%2C%E2%80%9D%20Proc.%20London%20Math.%20Soc.%204%2C%20253%E2%80%93283%20%281872%29&btnG=) since the time of Lord Rayleigh.

The exact solution of the wave equation for scattering of waves by a sphere is much trickier and has been dealt with in two relatively recent papers - [here](https://academic.oup.com/imajna/article/34/2/675/686481) and [here](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0021999114003945?token=6044EEC1A6123343C0FE55BDB5C33892A0EB61CD11642BD67D2AEE32B406E07D3370CAB7965F09E1B89210903FFE20EA).

I have been trying to determine whether there exists an exact solution for the wave equation in the two-dimensional case, i.e. for a disk/cylinder. It is not mentioned in the recent papers I listed above for the case of the sphere, and I haven't been able to find anything despite an extensive search of the literature.

Does anyone know if an exact solution of the wave equation for the scattering of waves by a disk/cylinder exists, or is this still an open problem?

Comment: What do you mean by the "exact solution"? The papers you refer to are about numerical solutions.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko - Maybe 'explicit representation' is a better term than 'exact solution.' I used the term 'exact solution' as that is how these representations are described in the first paper I referred to. Equation (4.18) for $\phi(t)$ in this paper for instance is referred to as a component of the 'exact solution' $\phi(t)Y_n^m$ even though it contains summations and integrals. So I am wondering if there exist analogous explicit representations for the two dimensional case?